# Iterating over rows, adding rows, and populating new column with sum of added rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dataframe and I need to add the rows in a column in succession. And have the result of populate the rows of a new column. Having some trouble getting started.

```
'column'              'new column'
   a                        a
   b                       a+b
   c                      a+b+c
```

Comment: Did you try `cumsum`?

Comment: oh great that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to do that in pandas:

```
df['new_column'] = df['column'].cumsum()
```